# In Emacs how to navigate back in Help mode

Tags: emacs

In the Help Mode, clicking on the links takes to a new buffer position, but the marks are not set, unlike the isearch, so to navigate to the previous position C-u C-SPACE does not work. How to navigate in the Help mode without using the mouse(In mouse clicking on the back text link navigates to the old position).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The key you are looking for is `C-c C-b` (and forward is `C-c C-f`).

Comment: there's another scenario, when I open a 2 column buffer which press ENTER on a link, it jumps to the link in the other window with mini-buffer display "Mark set". I guess there is a quick way to jump back.